# Lair Rally points messing up

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg

SC2 HotS multiplayer. Whenever I upgrade to a lair or hive as zerg my rally points get cancelled and sometimes just as a hatchery it happens too. I'm needless missing mining time and have units out of position anyone having the same issue or know whats going on here?

Comment: Is it possible you're right-clicking on the hatchery with the hatchery selected? That will cancel the rally points.

Comment: You should make a replay of game where it happens to you. Will make it easier to narrow it down.

Comment: It could be occurring because you're right-clicking on the lair while it's selected, as others have said. If you aren't making that mistake, it could be a legit bug. I main zerg and haven't noticed anything like this, but consider filing a bug report [here](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/13440/).

Answer (score 3):

as Tenfour mentions in the comments, right-clicking on the hatchery while the building is selected (or any other structure) will cancel the rally points, (or equivalently, sets the building itself to be the rally point).